# JavaFx set volume on MediaPlayer not working

Tags: javafx-8, media-player

This question has been asked before but to date there is no answer. I have just struck the same problem. I traced into the mediaplayer source and all is well until I get to gstSetVolume in GSTMediaPlayer for which I don't have the source.
At that point the volume value is still correct.

After setting the volume System.out.println(player.getVolume()); reports the correct value (0.0 - 1.0) BUT the volume has not changed. If the slider is set to 0, the audio is muted. Any other value is full volume.

Platform is Netbeans 8.1 on Windows 7 with JavaFX-8 and JDK-8 and the media source is a standard mp4 which works on all tested players (Windows, VLC etc).

Here is the code attached to a MediaView (which works well):

```
Runnable videoLoop;
PlayListViewController playListViewController;

// Videos are looped here
public void startVideoLoop() {

    playerIndex = 0;

    videoLoop = () -> {
        // Previous player MUST be stopped otherwise it is left
        // in the PLAYING state and the next video will not PLAY
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        // Point to the next player
        if (++playerIndex == videoPlayersList.size()) {
            playerIndex = 0;
        }

        playVideoSequence();
    };

    playVideoSequence();
}

public void playVideoSequence() {

    // If the video options are shown we can update the listview
    if (playListViewController != null) {
        playListViewController.setListViewItem(playerIndex);
    }
    player = videoPlayersList.get(playerIndex);

    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(videoLoop);
    player.play();
}
```

A right mouse button press then invokes a 'settings' option. This is a View Controller which is attached to an FXML view. The controller receives a reference to the videoField when it is invoked. Here is the relevant snippet:

```
private void setHandlers() {

    idVolumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

            // videoField is a separate class
            videoField.setVolume(idVolumeSlider.getValue());
        }
    });
```

I'm sorry I cannot supply a 'cut and paste' example, because that would mean a lot of pruning and simplifying of classes to achieve that with the risk of introducing additional problems.

Comment: I thought I should add the fact that I'm trying to change the volume of a player that's playing a video. If I set the volume before calling play() then it works fine. As soon as is plays however, nothing seems to be able to change the volume.

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you post a [MCVE]?